# ugettext_lazy doesn't work with reportlab's Table

Tags: python, django, reportlab

When I try to use `ugettext_lazy` with reportlab's Table class, instead of displaying the default text when there is no translation, the output displays `django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0xb54921ec` For example,

```
import ugettext_lazy as _

heading = (_('Service'), _('Price'), _('Note'))
table = Table([heading])
```

And the output is as described above. Has anyone encoutered this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code may rely on objects being actual strings and not lazy objects. Try to use regular ugettext. In this case strings will be translated before passing into reportlab

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

heading = (_('Service'), _('Price'), _('Note'))
table = Table([heading])
```